# aptana 3 (eclipse?) memory usage grows quickly

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I use Aptana 3 (the standalone version), but I have a problem when I use it in huge javascript files like libraries. Memory usage grow up fastly when I code and it become laggy, in task manager it grow up from nearly 150mb to 600+mb, then it become unusable so I have to close and reopen Aptana.
I googled to solve my problem but nothing was useful. Is it possible to change some parameter to adjust memory usage? (maybe at 600+mb it swap?)
This is wat I get from diagnostic test

```
Host OS: Windows 7
JRE Version: 1.6.0_24
Version: 3.2.1.201207261642
VM Arguments: -Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Answer (score 0):

Aptana is basically an Eclipse RCP so you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse) for suggestions.